# Facebook api graph doesn't return the from field when i execute the call

Tags: facebook-graph-api

hi everyone i am executing the following call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/{my-page-id-linked-to-the-app}/feed?access_token={page-access-token}&appsecret_proof={my-app_secret-proof}&fields=from, message, comments.limit(100){from, message, comments.limit(100){from, message, comments.limit(100){from,message}}}
```

response

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "message": "ciao",
        "id": "the-id"
    }, 
etc,etc
```

]}

but when i execute the call i retrive only partial information without form  field.
Did someone have this problem, and in case how do you manage? ty in advice

p.s. i retirve only the from where the user has a role in the app

Comment: Is your app still in dev mode? Then it is probably on purpose, that you don't get info about users that don't have a role in the app.

Comment: Hi, i though the same but i checked and my app is live and business

Comment: Issues like this have come up before, and there are several bug reports, such as https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/310828657546046/ I can't tell you whether it is actually buggy, or if Facebook deliberately wants to protect privacy here though.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook add a new permision that allow you to retrivce that information.
The permision is ""Business Asset User Profile Access"